# Taking a DSV file and giving each column its own array

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I've got a DSV file with these columns
"TITLE"                     "STARRING"                          "DIRECTOR"
I'd like to put each column in an array. e.g. Title array would first have TITLE then movie titles so on and so forth. But I'm facing a problem in getting them into the arrays.

```
 //Variables used
    int index = 0;
    String[] Title = new String[10];
    String[] Date = new String[10];


    //File dir and object
    String File = "DSV.txt";
    File DSV = new File(File);

    //Scanner&Delimiter
    Scanner Read = new Scanner(DSV);
    Read.useDelimiter("\"\\s*(.*?)\\s*\"");


    //While loop to iterate through the entire file
    while (Read.hasNext())
    {
        Title[index]=Read.next();
        Date[index]=Read.next();
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Names));
```

I've used the solutions found in this site, and I've gotten either nulls and commas or the entire DSV file in one index. Does anyone know how to get the values in each line in order and insert them into the array? keep in mind that there is whitespace of various sizes (spaces and tabs) in between.

Answer (score -1):

try using the delimiter pattren: \"\s*\",,

pattern
\ " \ \ s * \ "